# Is there a way to prevent WebVOWL creating undefined union classes?

Tags: visualization, rdf, owl, ontology, linked-data

I'm working on a digital humanities project where I'm trying to use WebVowl to visualise an ontology I made in Protégé. When I import the ontology into WebVowl it generates a lot of undefined union classes that make it impossible to export as TTL. It gives the message:

Warning:
Can not export ontology
Reason:
Detected unsupported ontology axioms, (e.g. owl:Union)
Action:
Ontology is not exported

[example of undefined union class that is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGP5F.png)

I have tried manually editing to remove these on a small sample of the ontology using edit mode and this makes exporting possible but is there a way to prevent the creation of these in the first place and show only the properties linked directly to their domains and ranges?

Any other work arounds or other software suggestions would also be welcome.